# rounding up to the multiplier

Tags: javascript, math

I am writing a javascript code which gives output of a `X` which always divisible by `Y`

For example if I have `7` which is not divisible by `4` but I want the code to add number up to `8`

This is the code I did, it works for `7`, but it should work for value `8`

```
var x = 7
var y = 4
x = x + (y - x%y)
console.log(x)
```

I get the output `8` which is correct, but

```
var x = 8
var y = 4
x = x + (y - x%y)
console.log(x)
```

I am getting `12` which is not correct, I want the same `8`

My question is, without putting an if condition how I will make this formula work?

Comment: Is the number 4 is always constant

Comment: it could be a variable, but for now it is 4, example `l = l + (y - l%y)`, I changed the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should also do it:

```js
var x = 8
var y = 4
x = x+y-(x-1)%y-1
console.log(x)
```

Comment: sorry I don't want any loop or if condition

Comment: The loop is only there to quickly demonstrate the result for a _sequence if numbers_. It is *not* part of the solution.

Comment: please modify the code without loop

Comment: Hey the solution is simply: `i+div-(i-1)%div-1` with `i` being your `x` and `div` being your `y`.

Comment: I modified the text myself to make it direct answer to suite the OP's code requirement

Comment: Be aware this may give you an unexpected result when running with x = 0 and also for non integer values of x like x = 4.4 and y = 8, you would still get 4.

Comment: if `x = 4.4` and `y = 8`, I am getting `8` only which is correct, if `x = 0` and `y = 4` then I also I want `4` which is also correct

Answer (score 4):

If I understood correctly, you're probably looking for something like this:

```js
Math.ceil(x / y) * y;
```

```js
function toNearestMultiple(x, y) {
    return Math.ceil(x / y) * y;
}

console.log(toNearestMultiple(7, 4));
console.log(toNearestMultiple(8, 4));
console.log(toNearestMultiple(9, 4));
```

Comment: sorry if I put 8 it gives my 12, so I cannot accept this solution

Comment: Math.ceil(8 / 4) * 4 = Math.ceil(2) * 4 = 2 * 4 = 8

Not sure what you did to get 12 with x = 8 and y = 4.

Comment: this is my bad, your code is correct